# What happens if you interrupt a POSTGRESQL database that's receiving data?

Tags: postgresql, backup, data-loss

I have a Docker application and as a quick and dirty backup strategy, I'm thinking to tar the whole project incrementally and send it off remotely.

I'd rather keep the services running while doing the tar operation.
The question arises, what happens if a client is writing data in the moment of tarring?

Will I have an incomplete or corrupt data entry?
If so, how much of a problem is that if you don't care about that data being lost?

The other strategy is to stop the docker container and then do the tar.
In that scenario, I still wonder what happens if somebody is writing data at the moment of shutdown.

It seems like both scenarios might suffer the same problem and if that is so, I might just as well leave the service running during the backup.

Postgresql version is 12.7 but if necessary, I think upgrading to 13.3 will pose no issues.

Comment: This will heavily depend on the specifics of which database system you're referring to, as there are minute differences between each system and version. Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: @J.D. Fair point, changes made.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! I presume that you use pg_dump (or similar) to take a dump of your running system? After that, there should be no problem tarring the dump (and other files?) - I mean, PostgreSQL will run even when there are other processes running that read and write to disk. Sure, it will put pressure on your I/O subsystem, but that's why many (most?) backups are taken at (say) 03:00 and not at 15:00!